# Minimize Form by user control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a user control that has three buttons on top Close , Minimize and On Top. When we drag that user control on windows form application and run it we can perform all three functionalities. But when i made my own user control and added these options only close could be added by implementing `Application.Exit();`but not topmost or minimize as they require form so how can we minimize the form by the usercontrol button

Comment: Is there absolutely no way you can reference the existing control which does actually work in the way you want?

Comment: that was designed for costumer by some one i have only dll file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your UserControl you have a ParentForm property, that should let you do what you want.

Comment: This works, provided you don't try hosting this control in anything other than a Windows Forms Form ;)

Comment: @Reed, yeah, apparently i stopped noticing missing WPF/WinForms/... tags.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing =- I just mentioned it, because it bit me once ;)  [I had already voted this one up, as it's correct...]  I've just found you never know where "reusable" user controls will end up in the future...